# Keep track of an accumulating total - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, accumulator

I am trying to keep track of an accumulating total within a function within JavaScript. For example, each time the user clicks the button on the webpage, the value produced should keep adding.

Comment: Okay, so what's the problem? Please show what you tried, and explain what you don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
var count = 0;

document.getElementById('buttonId').onclick = function(){ count++ }
```

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion:

HTML

```
<button>Add</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Javascript

```
var result = 0;
var res_div = document.getElementById('result');
var button = document.querySelector('button');
button.onclick = function () {
    result++;
    res_div.innerHTML = result;
};
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NmZky/)